# Threading to remove lag on process

Tags: python, multithreading

Hi Good day every one I'm an beginner of python programming. And I just wanna ask how can I thread this to make my program faster? Because I put some argument that if it my program will detect unknown face it will (playsound) but every time it play sound it like a kind of lag or stop sometime and it continue again if the sound is stopped by the way the sound has 2s length. Thank you in advance

Here's my code:

```
 from playsound import playsound
 if confidence>70:
                cv2.putText(img, datas, (x,y+205), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.putText(img, datas1, (x,y+230), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.putText(img, datas2, (x,y+250), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.putText(img,"Temp  " + get_temp(ser), (x,y+270), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, color, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                #markattend(datas,datas1,datas2)

                if get_temp(ser) > "37.0":
                    playsound('C:/Users/So_Low/Desktop/Offrecog/Beep.mp3')
            else:
                cv2.putText(img, "UNKNOWN", (x,y+205), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                playsound('C:/Users/So_Low/Desktop/Offrecog/Beep.mp3')
        return img
```

Can someone can help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The, very minimal, docs for the `playsound` package suggest that passing `block=False` will make the function run asynchronously which should hopefully not block or cause your "lag"

Comment: Ohw I see it now It wont stop the program now. Thanks a lot for your help